# Will installing kali linux automatically add a grub bootloader even if I already have it?

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot, gparted

I have a Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot on my laptop, I'd like to turn it into a *triple boot* with kali linux, the fact is I already have grub as the ubuntu installer added it.

After a bit of research I found out that kali adds it too (not sure but probably something debian does that both keeped, I never used debian if not on a live usb).

How can I prevent it from doing so? Also, to make space for kali I want to shrink the Windows partition, but I don't know how to do it from windows and Gparted gives me a warning and doesn't let me resize it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your third operating system finishes it's installation, choose Ubuntu and then run following commands (in Ubuntu).

Reinstall GRUB: `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`
Reboot: `shutdown -r now`
Restore the GRUB menu: `update-grub`

You will have Ubuntu grub bootloader :)

Nice tip: Your BIOS may have option to protect boot sector.

EDIT:

Regarding resizing, do not attempt to resize a partition on a device that is in use.

Please use LIVE CD and unmount your drive and then resize partition you want.

Comment: Thanks, got any tips on the second question?

Comment: Please look at my edit :) You cant resize partition if you are using it. Use some linux live cd/usb to do so.

Comment: If I helped click on ^ and ✓

Comment: I put it as the accepted answer but I can't upvote as I'm under 15 reputation, sorry

Comment: hey I forgot to reboot and  mistakenly shut down. Now I see a bash-like screen (grub) and I update-grub is not working! Help me please I'm confused

Comment: You can just download boot repair iso from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/
Burn it to flash drive or cd, it will fix your grub and you will have option to choose between installed systems.

Comment: have you succeeded?

Comment: I'm trying right now I'll let you know, thanks

Comment: now it reboots into windows, no grub, neither bash-like and gui. I used reccomended repair, might it be that this is happening because at the moment I ran the command you provided in the answer the windows partition was mounted on /mnt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54818/discussion-between-tommaso-thea-cioni-and-luka).